# Why can't powershell convert my password from system.string to system.security.securestring?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, user-profile-service

I'm trying to create a UPS sync connection using powershell. Becuase of the vagaries of our AD setup I can't use the Central Admin 'Create New Connection' function.

I am using the script below which is copied directly from the technet article on the AddSPProfileSyncConnection command and modified with our deployments data.

```
Add-SPProfileSyncConnection -ProfileServiceApplication 3b0a7b01-d954-4120-90b5-caa9382ebd9a -ConnectionDomain MyNETBIOS  -ConnectionForestName My.Forest.Name -ConnectionPassword convertto-securestring "Password" -asplaintext -force -ConnectionSynchronizationOU TopOU -ConnectionUserName Domain\svc_spdev_pfl -ConnectionPort 389
```

When I run the script I get an error message:

> Cannot bind parameter 'ConnectionPassword' Cannot convert the
>   "convertto-securestring" value of type "System.String" to type
>   "System.Security.SecureString".

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Try this on your password string  $PlainPassword = "P@ssw0rd"
$SecurePassword = $PlainPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

Answer (score 8, accepted):

convert the password into a varible that you can pass:

```
$secureString = convertto-securestring "Password" -asplaintext -force
```

now just use that converted secure string:

```
Add-SPProfileSyncConnection -ProfileServiceApplication 3b0a7b01-d954-4120-90b5-caa9382ebd9a -ConnectionDomain MyNETBIOS  -ConnectionForestName My.Forest.Name -ConnectionPassword $secureString -ConnectionSynchronizationOU TopOU -ConnectionUserName Domain\svc_spdev_pfl -ConnectionPort 389
```

Comment: no probs happy to hellp!